# How to creating an application launcher Desktop icon for Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: 16.04, android, android-emulator

I want to know is it possible for creating a application launcher icon for a specific version of **Emulator**(Android Studio) like ***Nexus_4_API_27***.

If you know please help me. Thanks in Advance.